# jquery autocomplete plugin that supports old browsers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Can anyone please suggest some good autocomplete plugins that are compatible with IE6 and above,FF 2+, Safari 3+, Opera 9+
I am currently using jquery 1.3 and Jquery UI 1.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/) will help you... I try this and it's working so great!